# How run hello_world example in pythons' faust lib

Tags: python, faust

my kafka deployed in kubernetes, so I forwarded port 9092

`kubectl port-forward -n kafka svc/kafka 9092`

and try run [hello_world.py](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/blob/master/examples/hello_world.py)
but faced with exception

**[2020-10-01 00:31:52,331] [3503] [ERROR] Unable connect to node with id 0: [Errno -2] Name or service not known**
**[2020-10-01 00:31:52,341] [3503] [ERROR] [^Worker]: Error: ConnectionError('No connection to node with id 0',)**

full stacktrace:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.7319.64)
+ƒaµS† v1.11.0a1-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id          | hello-world-alex                                                       |
| transport   | [URL('kafka://localhost:9092')]                                        |
| store       | memory:                                                                |
| web         | http://desktop-jd8f1bk:6066                                            |
| log         | -stderr- (info)                                                        |
| pid         | 3503                                                                   |
| hostname    | DESKTOP-JD8F1BK                                                        |
| platform    | CPython 3.6.9 (Linux x86_64)                                           |
| drivers     |                                                                        |
|   transport | aiokafka=1.1.6                                                         |
|   web       | aiohttp=3.6.2                                                          |
| datadir     | /mnt/c/work/dev/project/python/faust/examples/hello-world-alex-data    |
| appdir      | /mnt/c/work/dev/project/python/faust/examples/hello-world-alex-data/v1 |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[2020-10-01 00:31:51,923] [3503] [INFO] [^Worker]: Starting... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:51,945] [3503] [INFO] [^-App]: Starting... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:51,945] [3503] [INFO] [^--Monitor]: Starting... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:51,946] [3503] [INFO] [^--Producer]: Starting... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:51,947] [3503] [INFO] [^---ProducerBuffer]: Starting... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,331] [3503] [ERROR] Unable connect to node with id 0: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,341] [3503] [ERROR] [^Worker]: Error: ConnectionError('No connection to node with id 0',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/worker.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self._starting_fut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 736, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 743, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 767, in _actually_start
    await child.maybe_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 795, in maybe_start
    await self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 736, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 743, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 767, in _actually_start
    await child.maybe_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 795, in maybe_start
    await self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 736, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 743, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mode/services.py", line 760, in _actually_start
    await self.on_start()
  File "/mnt/c/work/dev/project/python/faust/faust/transport/drivers/aiokafka.py", line 1022, in on_start
    await producer.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/producer/producer.py", line 178, in start
    await self.client.bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 235, in bootstrap
    self._api_version = await self.check_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/aiokafka/client.py", line 533, in check_version
    "No connection to node with id {}".format(node_id))
kafka.errors.ConnectionError: ConnectionError: No connection to node with id 0
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,354] [3503] [INFO] [^Worker]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,355] [3503] [INFO] [^-App]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,356] [3503] [INFO] [^-App]: Flush producer buffer... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,357] [3503] [INFO] [^--TableManager]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,358] [3503] [INFO] [^---Fetcher]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,359] [3503] [INFO] [^---Conductor]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,360] [3503] [INFO] [^--AgentManager]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,361] [3503] [INFO] [^Agent: __main__.print_greetings]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,362] [3503] [INFO] [^--ReplyConsumer]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,363] [3503] [INFO] [^--LeaderAssignor]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,364] [3503] [INFO] [^--Consumer]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,367] [3503] [INFO] [^--Web]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,368] [3503] [INFO] [^--CacheBackend]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,369] [3503] [INFO] [^--Producer]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,369] [3503] [INFO] [^---ProducerBuffer]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,372] [3503] [INFO] [^--Monitor]: Stopping... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,374] [3503] [INFO] [^Worker]: Gathering service tasks... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:52,375] [3503] [INFO] [^Worker]: Gathering all futures... 
[2020-10-01 00:31:54,404] [3503] [INFO] [^Worker]: Closing event loop 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

could you explain, what should I fix

Answer (score 0):

I use wsl
[image]
so after added to `/etc/hosts` line 
`127.0.0.1       kafka-0.kafka-headless.kafka.svc.cluster.local`
I've solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For me on macOS helped add this line to `/etc/hosts`:

`127.0.0.1 kafka`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).